# Styling WPF ScrollViewer To Appear Like VS2010 Tabs Scroller

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm using AvalonDock to develop a tool for internal use by our developers and QA.  I am working on a custom version of the VS2010 style that is provided in the Themes.  The style just didn't function enough like VS2010 for me to be happy with it.  I've made almost all the color and image changes and I just noticed that the tabs in the DocumentPane do not scroll like VS2010 when there are more tabs than can fit in the header area.

Since I have the complete style in my project I found the area where the styles are applied.  I placed a ScrollViewer around the ad:DocumentTabPanel thinking I could somehow restyle the horizontal scrollbar so that there would be an arrow on the left and on the right of the tabs.

Is this possible?

[image: Example of overflow scrolling in VS2010]

Here is the style after my base modifications but without any modification to the scrollviewer:

```
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ad:DocumentPane}" TargetType="{x:Type ad:DocumentPane}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey {x:Type ad:DockingManager}, {x:Static ad:AvalonDockBrushes.DefaultBackgroundBrush}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ad:DocumentPane}" >
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <ContextMenu x:Key="DocumentsListMenu" StaysOpen="True"  />
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Border 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="PART_Header" 
                            Grid.Row="0" 
                            Focusable="False" 
                            >
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" CanContentScroll="True">

                                        <ad:DocumentTabPanel 
                                          x:Name="paneTabsPanel" 
                                          Panel.ZIndex ="1" 
                                          IsItemsHost="True" 
                                          TabItemStyle="{StaticResource CustomDocumentTabItemStyle}"/>

                                </ScrollViewer>
                                <Button x:Name="PART_ShowContextMenuButton" 
                                        Grid.Column="2"
                                        Width="15" Height="15" 
                                        Style="{StaticResource PaneHeaderCommandStyle}">
                                    <Image x:Name="ShowContextMenuIcon" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/Dev2010/PinMenu.png" Width="13" Height="13" Stretch="None"/>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                            <Border 
                                x:Name="topBorder"
                                Height="4"
                                Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey {x:Type ad:DockingManager}, {x:Static ad:AvalonDockBrushes.DocumentHeaderBorder}}}" 
                                CornerRadius="2,2,0,0" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                >
                            </Border>
                            <Border
                                x:Name="bottomBorder"
                                Height="4"
                                Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey {x:Type ad:DockingManager}, {x:Static ad:AvalonDockBrushes.DocumentHeaderBorder}}}" 
                                CornerRadius="0,0,2,2" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                >
                            </Border>
                            <ContentPresenter 
                                    Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedItem.Content}"
                                    Margin="0,4,0,4"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                                    />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                        
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ShowHeader" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="PART_Header" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMainDocumentPane, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Images/Dev2010/PinDockMenu.png" TargetName="ShowContextMenuIcon"/>
                    </DataTrigger>-->

                                                <Trigger Property="ContainsActiveDocument" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" 
                                Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey {x:Type ad:DockingManager}, {x:Static ad:AvalonDockBrushes.DocumentHeaderBorderSelected}}}" 
                                TargetName="topBorder"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" 
                                Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey {x:Type ad:DockingManager}, {x:Static ad:AvalonDockBrushes.DocumentHeaderBorderSelected}}}" 
                                TargetName="bottomBorder"/>
                                                </Trigger>

                                                <Trigger Property="ContainsActiveContent" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" 
                                Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey {x:Type ad:DockingManager}, {x:Static ad:AvalonDockBrushes.DocumentHeaderBorderSelectedActivated}}}" 
                                TargetName="topBorder"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" 
                                Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey {x:Type ad:DockingManager}, {x:Static ad:AvalonDockBrushes.DocumentHeaderBorderSelectedActivated}}}" 
                                TargetName="bottomBorder"/>
                                                </Trigger>

                                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    From="0" To="1"  Duration="0:0:0.200" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                                </EventTrigger>
                                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this in the past, and found it easiest to hide the ScrollViewer's ScrollBar, and manually scroll the content when two RepeatButtons are pressed.

The code I originally started with can be found [here](http://www.blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/02/10/TabControlStyling_PartThree.aspx), but the basic idea is to overwrite the ScrollViewer's template to look something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0" Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" Content="<" />
    <RepeatButton Grid.Column="2" Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" Content=">" />

    <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.Content}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Ok, I think I was going in the same direction about the same time I saw this.  Cool!  I'm glad we came to the same conclusion.  However, don't you need the ScrollContentPresenter in there somewhere?  I'm looking at the MSDN style and template page for the scroll viewer.

Comment: @MikeG Yes, you can find the full template in the link above. I was just trying to keep the code simple for the sake of simplicity, but I can see where that could cause confusion. Its added it to my answer.

Comment: Ok. Just making sure. I'm new to this styling stuff. Now I just have to override some AvalonDock code that removes the tab headers from view if they're overflowed and the scroller should work.  Thanks!

Comment: I thought this was the answer.  I really did!  However, it's not working for me.  I've fought with the content not scrolling all day, but it appears as if the RepeatButtons are not firing the scroll events.  When I wrap my content with a plain old ScrollViewer it does scroll.  Odd!

Comment: Ok, figured out the issue.  The scroll viewer was not respecting the RepeatButton events until HorizontalScrollBarVisibility is set to Visible.  I just included that in my style for the ScrollViewer and I'm golden!  Hopefully this isn't confusing when you read it!